# Redirect on condition in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to make some redirects on the one condition, using `If` block in Apache, in the .htaccess of my project. I have this:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'shoppingmall-local.ventajon.com:8433'">
  # inicio
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/tiendas-online$ https://shoppingmall-local.ventajon.com/tiendas-online

  # carrito de compras
  Redirect 301 /tiendas-online/cart https://shoppingmall-local.ventajon.com/tiendas-online/cart

# cuenta
  Redirect 301 /tiendas-online/cuenta https://shoppingmall-local.ventajon.com/tiendas-online/cuenta
</If>
```

But it doesn't work. When I click in the link, it doesn't redirect. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'shoppingmall-local.ventajon.com:8433'` is _not_ a valid hostname. It is the combination of a hostname and a port number maybe, seprated by a colon.

Comment: @arkascha The `Host` header (`HTTP_HOST` server variable) does not only contain the hostname. The port number _is_ part of the `Host` header (separated by a colon) if it is included in the request.

Comment: What is the actual URL you are requesting, and what other directives do you have (and where, in relation to the code block you've posted)? Does port 8433 (perhaps that should be 8443?) and port 443 point to the same place?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, `:8433` and `:443` are pointing to the same place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not stated the URL you are requesting (when you "click in the link") or (importantly) what other directives you have in the config file (and the corresponding placement of these directives).

In isolation there's nothing actually wrong with the rule block you've posted (so it's likely there is a conflict with other directives), however, these rules can be simplified using mod_rewrite (which you are most certainly using already to root these requests).

Try the following instead at the *top* of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(shoppingmall-local\.ventajon\.com):8433$
RewriteRule ^tiendas-online(/cart|/cuenta)?$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This essentially does the same as your existing rule block. (Except that it won't redirect `/tiendas-online/cart/<something>` and `/tiendas-online/cuenta/<something>` as the `Redirect` directives would.) This rule *must* go near the top of the `.htaccess` file before any existing mod_rewrite directives.

I'm assuming your source URLs do not contain a trailing slash.

(You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if is already occurs later in the config file.)

I mentioned this in comments (and this was seemingly confirmed), however, `8433` does look-like a typo. It would be more common to be using `8443` as an alternative port for HTTPS, not `8433` as you have written here?

You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and you should ensure the browser (and any intermediary) cache is cleared before testing.

If you only have one *hostname* (ie. `shoppingmall-local\.ventajon\.com`) then the rule can be simplified further since you can just check for the port number instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =8433
RewriteRule ^tiendas-online(/cart|/cuenta)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```